# Client wrapper for sending data to a downstream process

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, enum

I am building a Python client for an alert process engine. The users can use this client to publish and clear the alerts. 
The client  exposes two methods publish and clear to the users. These methods accept some parameters which would define the alerts from the users and enriches them with a few more fields and validates it. But so far there is no logical validation needed other than the type checking of the fields input by the users. The scripts also converts this data to a json fromat. The json data will be sent to the downstream process. Before sending, this data will be validated against a json schema which I haven't implemented yet. 
The client will be packaged as a library eventually and made available to the users. This is how the current version of the main script looks like.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

"""Main module."""

from enum import Enum
import json
import datetime


class AlertStatus(Enum):
    OPEN = 0
    CLOSED = 1


class AlertSeverity(Enum):
    EXCEPTION = 1
    WARNING = 2
    NOTIFICATION = 3



class AlertRequest:
    def __init__(self, run_date, application_id, data_process_key):
        self.param_dict = {"run_date": run_date,
                           "application_id": application_id,
                           "data_process_key": data_process_key}

    def _to_json(self, input_dict):
        return json.dumps(input_dict)

    def prepare_to_publish(self, severity, **kwargs):
        self.param_dict["status"] = AlertStatus.OPEN.name
        self.param_dict["severity"] = severity
        self.param_dict["owner"] = kwargs.get("owner", None)
        self.param_dict["data"] = kwargs.get("data", None)
        self.param_dict["alert_links"] = kwargs.get("alert_links", None)
        self.param_dict["event_date_time"] = datetime.datetime.now().isoformat()
        return self._to_json(self.param_dict)

    def prepare_to_clear(self):
        """Update the status of alert to closed"""
        self.param_dict["status"] = AlertStatus.CLOSED.name
        return self._to_json(self.param_dict)


def publish(run_date, application_id, data_process_key, severity="WARNING", **kwargs):
    """
    :param run_date: Run date of the data process in a sring format specified in the json schema
    :param application_id:
    :param data_process_key:
    :param severity:
    A number of optional keyword arguments may be specified

    Owner     Two types - 1. functional group (research group or data owner)
                          and 2 a set of functional groups a user is interested in (data rotation)
    Data      Custom dictionary to specify any additional attributes.

    Alert Links  List of links for action or sourcing debug data for display in custom views
    :return:
    """
    alert_req_obj = AlertRequest(run_date, application_id, data_process_key)
    req_payload = alert_req_obj.prepare_to_publish(severity, **kwargs)
    print(req_payload)
    return True


def clear(run_date, application_id, data_process_key):

    alert_req_obj = AlertRequest(run_date, application_id, data_process_key)
    req_payload = alert_req_obj.prepare_to_clear()
    print(req_payload)
    return True

if __name__ == "__main__":
    publish('2019-07-01', 1234, 'alert')
    clear('2019-07-01', 1234, 'alert')
```

This is the first time I am trying to make use of the enum class in Python. But so far I don't think they are actually making the code better if not complicating it.
I would really appreciate some constructive criticism on the structure, design, the methods implemented or the approach. Please let me know how can I make this better.
The downstream process would be a REST end point or a queue. But the process expects that data is a valid json format. Is there a type checking needed in this case to ensure that the json is valid?